# Function as property in React.js + TypeScript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What are the differences between this syntax? What types will they have?

eg:

```
const foo = () => (<>Something...</>);  

const bar = (arg: string) => (<>{arg}</>);

interface IComponent {
property: ???
}

<Component property={foo} />
<Component property={foo()} />
<Component property={() => foo} />
<Component property={() => foo()} />
<Component property={() => bar(arg)} />
<Component property={bar(arg)} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to set a React Component as a property you should go with `ReactElement` or `ReactNode`. These types can be imported by the `react` component.

Also then only your first definition is valid. (Okay Maybe second and last one too, but that is not what you really want.

Your result:

`property: ReactElement`

Definition 3 is function that returns a function, so the valid syntax should be:

`property: () => () => ReactElement<{args: string}>`

Definition four and five is a simpler for. It directly returns a React Node:

`property: () => ReactElement` or
`property: () => ReactElement<{args: string}>`

It depends how your component should look like :)